# memory allocation size upper bound 20MB in my dll

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, dll

I'm Having trouble with creating my own DLL (for academic..).

In DLL project's header(compile option is "C"),
I declared three function to export

```
// in dll1 header

#pragma once

#ifdef MYDLL
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


MYDLL_API int Mmalloc(int**, int);
MYDLL_API int Mfree(int**);
MYDLL_API int Arrsum(int*, int);
```

they are just easy function.

and in DLL .C

```
 //in dll.c 

#include "dll1.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int Mmalloc(int** mem, int n) // just memory Allocation
{
    *mem = (int*)malloc(sizeof(n)*sizeof(int));
    if (*mem) return 1; // if succeed return 1
    return 0;           // or return zero
};

int Mfree(int** mem) // just memory Free
{
    free(*mem);
    return 1;
}

int Arrsum(int* arr, int n) // just some operate
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

with "Preprocess Define"-> "MYDLL" and also "Runtime Library"->"/MD"
I build it.

and I create another project (compile Option "default (c++)")
add add header from DLL header add extern "C"

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MYDLL
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


extern "C"
{
    MYDLL_API int Mmalloc(int**, int);
    MYDLL_API int Mfree(int**);
    MYDLL_API int Arrsum(int*, int);
}
```

and I also made main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dll1.h"

#define SZ 1000

int main()
{
    int* arr=0;
    int cnt = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        int ret = Mmalloc(&arr, SZ);
        printf(ret ? "YES\n" : "NO\n");

        for (int i = 1; i <= SZ; i++)
        {
            arr[i - 1] = i;
            printf("%d\n", arr[i - 1]);
        }

        printf("%d\n", Arrsum(arr, SZ));

        printf("cnt : %d\n", ++cnt);
        Mfree(&arr);
    }
};
```

and I place *.dll, *.lib file place in a right folder.
It seems work well for me just moment, but i found huge error.

I used `while(1)` syntax in main.cpp.
so my program should work as long as It could, but It stops at some points.

I couldn't figure out what is a real problem.

I changed heaps reserve size in .dll project, and also in main.cpp project

but my main program always stops.

In debug mode, It stops 
[image: .dll, break point trigger]

or with more size (SZ 10000~100000) I have an access violation
[image: access violation]

Please help me.. I can't even imagine what the real problem is.

Is there some syntax error  in dll? (memory allocation in function?)
or 
a Compiler Issue? , Windows? or what?...

Comment: why I wrote my post's title with "20MB" word is It usually stops after 2000~ 8000 array size allocation . 5000 * 4BYTE = 20,000BYTE = 20MB approximately.
Sorry for ambiguity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Mmalloc` is allocating 4 or 8 ints (depending on the value of `sizeof(n)` on your system), not `n` ints. Your program then exhibits undefined behavior by way of a buffer overrun.

Comment: Real thanks!! . I made what a fool mistake... with out your comment , i would spend lots of time on this problem real thankx